# How can I display simple tooltips on icons in html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tooltip, activescaffold

I am using ActiveScaffold in a Ruby on Rails app, and to save space in the table I have replaced the default "actions" text in the table (ie. "edit", "delete", "show") with icons using CSS. I have also added a couple of custom actions with action_link.add ("move" and "copy").

For clarity, **I would like to have a tooltip pop up with the related action** (ie. "edit", "copy") when I hover the mouse over the icon.

I thought I could do this by adding a simple "alt" definition to the  tag, but that doesn't appear to work.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `alt` attribute is to be used as an alternative to the image, in the case of the image missing, or in a text only browser.

IE got it wrong, when they made `alt` appear as a tooltip. It was never meant to be that.

The correct attribute for this is `title`, which of course doesn't do a tooltip in IE.

So, to do have a tooltip show up in both IE, and FireFox/Safari/Chrome/Opera, use both an `alt` attribute and a `title` attribute.

Comment: YUI provides a [ToolTip widget](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/tooltip/) for cross-browser purposes.

Comment: Also, title actually does display a tooltip in IE.

Comment: actually as @nertzy indicated IE will render either the alt or the title attribute but will correctly use the title attribute if both are supplied.  Using `title` is recommended.

Answer (score 9):

Just a minor point to add to this thread... there is no alt tag or title tag.  The alt attribute is for images, but all other elements on a page can have a title attribute, which is the best choice for cross browser compatibility.

```
<span title="Click here to edit the foo">
  Edit
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want a "title" tag.  I'm not sure if this is necessary anymore, but I usually add both alt and title tags to make sure all browsers display the tool tip the same.

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips in HTML are the contents of the `alt` text for image tags, but if you're setting this using CSS you probably have a `background:url(...);` style instead of an image.

Comment: Great insight - yes, this is the case, I am using a background image instead of an <img>

Answer (score 1):

Use `alt` on the images and `title` on the links.

Answer (score 1):

The alt property of an img tag works in some browsers, but not all (such as some mozilla-based ones).

The "[right way](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/web-developer/faq.html#alttooltip)" to do this is to use the title property.

Answer (score 0):

As Prestaul pointed out, the alt tag should work for images and title for links. However, this is also browser dependent...most browsers **should** implement functionality that displays this metadata as tooltips but they aren't required to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Realizing, as Joel Coehoom pointed out, that my icon was actually a background image, I created a transparent.gif image with title and alt attributes over top of the background, and voila - tooltips!

Answer (score 0):

good tool here
http://www.guangmingsoft.net/htmlsnapshot/html2image.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the tag abbr and the tittle atribute with your test
eg `<abbr tittle="some text"> </abbr>`
as that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61601175/9442717