# Making a simple tooltip with only HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I want my tooltip element (the `<span>`) to appear **above everything on the page** but **still relative to its parent element** (the `<td>`). I'm trying with JS but would like a no-script solution.

JS to show/hide the `<span>`:

```
window.AETid = "AE";

        function tooltip(tid) {
         document.getElementById(tid).style.display="block";
        }

        function hideTooltip(tid) {
         document.getElementById(tid).style.display="none";
        }
```

HTML:

```
<td class="ht" onmouseover="tooltip(window.AETid);" onmouseout="hideTooltip(window.AETid);">
Send reminders?
<span class="tooltip" id="AE">If this option is selected, e-mail reminders will be sent to the client before each appointment.</span>
</td>
```

CSS for `.tooltip`:

```
.ht { position: relative; }
    .tooltip {
        color: #ff0000;
        display: none;
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
        right:0px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Currently, the tooltip appears as expected when I hover over the `<td>`, but it appears within the  element, thus changing the size of the `<td>` and thus the `<tr>` and thus the whole dang `<table>`. I want the tooltip to appear, well, like tooltips do: above and not effecting the rest of the page. z-index doesn't seem to do it alone in my case...

Using `position: fixed` instead of `absolute` on the tooltip `<span>` kept the element from interrupting the DOM, but literally positioned it after everything else on the page (at the bottom)

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Position needs to be `absolute` or `fixed`. The position right now is relative, which will effect the position of other `relative` or `static` positioned elements

Comment: I tried it using `relative` on the parent and `absolute` on the tooltip `<span>` (and edited the question to clarify). The tooltip is still interrupting the DOM flow. Using `fixed` made it positioned after everything else on the page

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found a method to make a very lightweight tooltip with no JS!

```css
.ht:hover .tooltip {
  display:block;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
    color: red;
    margin-left: 28px; /* moves the tooltip to the right */
    margin-top: 15px; /* moves it down */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td class="ht">Send reminders?
  <span class="tooltip">this is the tooltip alshdgwh gahfguo 
  wfhg fghwoug wugw hgrwuog hwaur guoarwhg rwu</span>
  </td>
</table>
```

Totally awesome and props to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359193/plain-javascript-tooltip/18359711#18359711)!

Comment: Usually not a fan of people co-opting other people's answers, even if you do give props, but in reducing that user's code down to its very basics, you've made this more valuable. Good job.

Answer (score 13):

just use abbr tag ?

```html
<p><abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948.</p>
<p title="Free Web tutorials">W3Schools.com</p>
```

Comment: I love the simplicity and that it does the job. Just used it. Thanks!

Comment: @dota2pro I absolutely appreciate this answer. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Just curious what is wrong with the title attribute of the td???

```html
<td title="If this option is selected, e-mail reminders will be sent to the client before each appointment.">
  Send reminders?
</td>
```

Comment: "Just curious what is wrong with the title attribute of the td?" There is a delay before it shows

Answer (score 1):

Try this its simple and compact,
I made it myself

```css
.info:hover .tooltip {
  color: red;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s
}
.tooltip {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s
}
}
.tooltip:hover {
  visibility: visible
}

.info {
cursor: help
}
```

```html
<span class="info">Text<span class="tooltip">MSG</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for tooltip ON TOP (always even if no space available)

```css
.ht:hover .tooltip {
    display:block;
}

.ht{
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<br><br><br><br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="ht">Send reminders? <br/> xaxaxa <br/> xaxaxa <br/> xaxaxa
<span class="tooltip">this is the tooltip alshdgwh gahfguo 
wfhg fghwoug wugw hgrwuog hwaur guoarwhg <br/> sdfaasdfrwu<br/> sdfaasdfrwu<br/> sdfaasdfrwu</span>
</>
```