# How do I use css to show on hover tool-tips using the same text which is shortend with ellipses?

Tags: html, css

I have the example where some of the strings are too long and I want them shortened. However, I want to be able to see the entire string when I hover my mouse over it.

```css
.don_single_donatori {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 310px;
}

.overview span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overview em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="don_single_donatori">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="overview">
      <p><span>This is my full name which should be shortend</span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
      <p><span>Anonymous</span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
      <p><span>Anonymous</span><em>500,00 EUR</em></p>
      <p><span>This is another long name that needs shortening</span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
      <p>Anonymous<em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
    </div>
```

Most approaches I found online use two strings, i.e. the text that you hover over with a mouse is seperate from the text you use for a tooltip (like in the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688025/making-a-simple-tooltip-with-only-html-and-css)). But in my case I have the same text. Having two entries for the same text seems redundant.

Comment: no way, use bootstrap or other jquery plugin for this

Comment: just in case: solution with `content: attr(title)` does allow you to use nested HTML tags. Or actually it allows but they will not be rendered as HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just use the title attribute of the span???

```html
<style>
.don_single_donatori {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 310px;
}

.overview span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.overview em {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000;
  float: right;
}
</style>
<div class="don_single_donatori">
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
            <p><span title="This is my full name which should be shortend">
            This is my full name which should be shortend
            </span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p><span>Anonymous</span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p><span>Anonymous</span><em>500,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p><span title="This is another long name that needs shortening">
            This is another long name that needs shortening
            </span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p>Anonymous<em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want duplicate text, use a CSS selector so that if the span has a title, use the title for content.  Then just remove the content in spans with a title as so:

```html
<style>
.don_single_donatori {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 310px;
}

.overview span {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.overview em {
    font-style: normal;
    color: #000;
    float: right;
}
span[title]::before {
    content: attr(title);
}
</style>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="don_single_donatori">
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="overview">
            <p><span title="This is my full name which should be shortend">
            </span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p><span>Anonymous</span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p><span>Anonymous</span><em>500,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p><span title="This is another long name that needs shortening">
            </span><em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
            <p>Anonymous<em>2.000,00 EUR</em></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe author can but is looking for different way without duplicating text

Comment: Yes,thank you, that will do it, but is there a way to do it without duplicating the text?

Comment: Without duplicating you could place the text as title attribute with span being empty and add it as 'content' to the span using css as shown in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50066521/9232222

Comment: great technique to follow thank you

Answer (score 1):

Extending the @Popmedic answer using [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) as content in pseudo element when hover:

```
<span  title="This is my full name which should be shortend"></span>
```

CSS

```
span {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
span:before {
 content: attr(title);
}
span:hover {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/PebeGy)

Answer (score 1):

Make the rest of `span` show through `overflow: visible;`, like so:

```
.overview p span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overview p:hover > span {
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1qf2wyz/)

You might still want to add more space between `span` and `em` so the text doesn't cover the text/numbers in `em`, but that depends on your design. Good luck!